# How can I specify the bind config in Consul config file?

Tags: consul

```
{
  "data_dir": "/tmp2/consul",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "server": true,
  "node_name": "master",
  "addresses": {
    "https": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "bind": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

Gives me an error of:

```
consul agent -config-file=cfg.json
==> Error parsing cfg.json: 1 error(s) occurred:

* invalid config key bind
```

Is there any documentation available for the JSON config file, as opposed to the command line parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#configuration-key-reference

```
bind_addr Equivalent to the -bind command-line flag.
```